# Creating polygons from points using Python

Tags: python, geopandas, interpolation, shapely, polygon-creation

I have a geopandas geodataframe with the following layout:

| Index | Cluster | Geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Point (x,y) |
| 2 | 2 | Point (x,y) |
| 3 | 4 | Point (x,y) |
| ... | ... | ... |

I can directly plot it, but it looks like crap, because I either every point is on its own or I have to create a buffer around it, which blurs the borders between clusters:

[image]
Therefore, I would like to bring all the points of a given cluster into one single polygon, so I can plot it more easily (e.g. by making a choropleth map).

However, I could not find a reliable way to do so. The solutions I found so far kind of randomly connect the points to a polygon, which results in polygons with weird shapes, that don't really follow the clusters.

How could this be accomplished?